# Wrong format: invalid address

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I hava a problem. I need to initialize the person having the address of the purse in the Javascript, then pass it to the function Solidity, but I get an error about wrong format.

My JavaScript function

```
 $scope.myToken = accounts[0];
 $scope.initProviders = function(providersAddresses,providersAmount){
  alert(providersAddresses);
  contract.init(providersAddresses,providersAmount,$scope.myToken).call();
 };
```

And call this function

```
<md-button ng-click="initProviders('0x199fdf564df1d18056ed46724582502fd3ce580a',1)">INIT</md-button>
```

And Solidity code

```
function init(address[] provAddrs, uint provCount,address mainAcc)
{
    clientAddr = mainAcc;
    for(uint i = 0;i<provCount;i++)
    {
        providers[i].profit = 0;
        providers[i].addr = provAddrs[0];
        provCount++;
    }
}
```

But after that I have error invalid address

Comment: Welcome! The [Ethereum StackExchange](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com) would have more people able to answer the question. (I'd answer it but don't know.)

Comment: Where is the object "contract"? Your function "init" does not show how it is part of the "contract" object. Also, you are using Typescript? "address[]" is not valid Javascript. Show more of your code, and provide the exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems, for the code you've shown, that the contract lacks initialization, at first.

```
var contract = eth.contract([abi])
                     .new([array of params], 
                     {data:'0x...', from:[address], gas:47000, gasPrice: 37891200});
```

Maybe you initalization lacks the 'from:[address]' attribute, that is required when sending a contract.

I would like to recommend you to try debbuging this call, with browser-solidity or calling this construction using web3 on browser or something, this error is thrown on **web3.js:3882** ... put a breakpoint there and see.